# mathematica first command always running, must abort evaluation for things to start working

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I recently installed Mathematica 10.0 and seem to have an annoying bug. The very first command always does not evaluate, it rather perpetually runs. I can do something trivial like "2" or "1+1", and it just keeps running, as if I put in some huge nonlinear equation solve or something.

However, if I abort this very first evaluation, then everything starts working normally. Has anyone come across this bug? Of course I can just go through this abort procedure every time, but I'm sure Wolfram did not intend their product to be used like this.

Comment: I had similar problem with v.8 when had [Agnitum Outpost Firewall](http://www.agnitum.ru/) installed. Which antivirus and/or firewall do you use?

Comment: It is convenient that you always see it happen. Create the smallest little notebook with anything that demonstrates this, provide any documentation you can, perhaps screenshots of Task Manager after five minutes, and get it off to Wolfram Support now! There is often an n.01 version and if you show them this serious problem then you might get it included. Wait too long and it may be a very long time before it gets fixed. Since thousands of people are using this now and there aren't thousands of identical complaints it may depend on your configuration or installation, but don't wait.

Comment: (This is OP) I'm not using any antivirus on my Mac. In fact, I tried this on both my Macbook Air and Mac Mini, both running Mavericks, and both had the exact same issue. In terms of "smallest notebook to reproduce the problem", that would have to be a blank notebook, since any command I enter will run forever. I have sent a message to Wolfram support. (Can you imagine Stephen Wolfram demonstrating Mathematica at some huge presentation and this happening? Brings back memories of the BSOD during that Bill Gates keynote)